# What are "additional points" awarded for?

Tags: battlefield-3

In Battlefield 3, sometimes at the end of a round, after my awards come in, I'll get one last bit of exp that's just called "additional points". It never counts towards any kit or weapon, just my rank.

It comes after I receive all of my points for ribbons or unlocks, and it doesn't come in the same batch. It has no picture next to it at all, it just says "Additional Points - +200"

I've had it about 4 times now, and every time it's only been 200 extra points.

What are these additional points awarded for?

Comment: I think it might be related to some unlocks, or even unlocking the last attachment on a gun. I seem to recall unlocking a scope (forget which one) and then clicking on it in the Unlocks page in between rounds and it had 200 points next to it

Comment: @Albort You always get 200 exp for every unlock, what I'm talking about is completely unrelated though.

Comment: I got it again last night. Could be for leveling up? Although that seems silly: "You leveled up. Have 200 points."

Comment: I've received it a couple of times today. Most of the time it's 200, but I also had one that was 2000, and another that was 3000. I still haven't figured out what it relates to yet.

Comment: I think i'll have to start keeping track of which games I get additional points in, so I can go back later into BattleLog and have a closer look. Might be the only way to work it out (short of an explanation from DICE, but where is the fun in that...)

Comment: I have checked the Battlelog after a game where I have received these 'additional points' and they are not listed in the details of the match. I will try to capture the results at the end of tonight's matches on video. This won't explain why they are being generated, but will add evidence to their occurrence.

Comment: I'm now starting to think that it is a "catch-all" in case of a glitch in the points system. I only say this because a mate joined a Conquest game just as it ended, and got the Additional Points (200), instead of Conquest Game (200)...

Comment: Once I joined a match, which ended two seconds before I spawned - all I got were those 200 addditional points. Just in case people thought you needed to do something to get these! We also lost the match, so I'm assuming it's the 200 from a conquest match ribbon, that wasn't awarded properly. (So the same as Albort's case, here)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sometimes the game will "forget" where certain points came from, and award them under additional points.

For example, I just received 2820 additional points *BUT* my jet score said that I'd scored 0 that round, but I'd actually scored the exact amount that I received in my additional points. It only forgot for the after round tally, as when I checked my vehicle tab, it remembered my actual amount of jet experience (I'd levelled up).

So it seems the varying amounts may be due to for instance, it not remembering that you got a particular ribbon, or a particular service medal.

Here's a video explaining what I mean. It's pretty bad quality, but as you can see, my jet score shows up as 0 when it's tallying points, and I gain 2820 "additional points". Then later when I switch to my vehicles tab, jets has +2820 experience.

Also, as of Back to Karkand (and I'm assuming future expansions will do this too) any assignments you complete will award you 5000 "Additional Points".

Additionally, any XP earned during a double XP weekend will earn you the same amount of XP extra under Additional Points.

Comment: Your case shows clearly this is a bug. I think DICE has programmed the scoring code defensively, so that anything which escapes the scoring classification lands in the category "additional points".

Comment: @Bora Yeah I think that's what happens as well.

Comment: This is so ridiculous but you seem to be absolute right about this. Thank you very much for telling is. -- I have no Idea how the game can simply forget it. but its better then just not givign you xp.

Answer (score 3):

Additional points count when you have 4 or 5 ribbons and the screen doesn't have time to list them out and if you get points for certain kills like roadkill and spotting can fall into that category too

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get a +2000 Additional Points at the end of a round yesterday. Im pretty sure this was because I got a service star (100 total kills with a particular weapon), this star wasn't included in the list of ribbons so it fits the 'Additional Points' quite well.

Comment: All the service stars I've ever received came up inside the awards area (with the ribbons).

Comment: Sometimes the game doesn't list all the awards/unlocks at the end of the round, so the points from the award/unlock are shown as "additional points".

Comment: @Pent So you mean this might be a bug?

Comment: @Bora Yes, this looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You might be observing the results of the match in terms of teams. If your team wins in a game of Rush, there is a Rush Winner pin awarded to each person on the winning team, which gives additional points.

Battlefield is predominately objective-based, so they have point systems in place to make sure you're rewarded for following the purpose of the game mode.

Comment: I believe what the OP is speaking about is the awards presentation after the round. It details the points earned for each class and then displays the Ribbons and associated points. At the end there is an award of (from what I have experienced) 200 "Extra Points". There is no ribbon, or any other icon above the Extra points.

Comment: @DavidGrove You're exactly correct. I'll edit the question to specify.

Comment: Maybe a hint in the general direction: Yesterday I took down a plane with a T-90, and got additional 200 points at the end of the round. I cannot see the direct relevance, because it was a regular kill, eventually, but still.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the round stats on Battlelog, there are awards given for "Top Jet", "Top Tank", "Top Engineer", etc.  Could it be that these +200 points are given out for those?

Comment: This is a very promising answer, but it also has a few flaws. I get top jet a lot, a lot more than I've seen the additional points. However with that said, yesterday I played jet for hours and saw it a lot more than I did any other day. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "glitch" happened because of service star, i got my refcon service star, and 5400 score, buty it just said +0 for recon kit, and 5400 additional points. However, like that one guy said, after checking kit tab, i saw i got my xp for recon.

Answer (score 1):

As a result of my findings, "additional points" come from three sources:

- The net code registers the score, but cannot decide what happened at the very moment it was earned.
- As regular classification, following actions bring additional points:

  1. Spotting, which leads to destroying of the spotted enemy / vehicle (assists)
  2. Class specific achievement awards (Top Jet, Engineer, etc.)
- And finally, extra XP gained on Double XP weekends (like [the one upcoming this week](http://www.gamezone.com/products/battlefield-3/news/dice-announces-first-battlefield-3-double-xp-weekend), 12.05.2012) will appear as "additional points" on your score tab.

Comment: Your first point is correct, as I've shown in my answer, but both of your other points aren't. Firstly, spotting just goes towards your regular kit points, otherwise I'd be getting additional point every single game, secondly, getting top jet or engineer or any of those doesn't give you any exp, and thirdly, I'm pretty sure there's no such thing as a double exp weekend.

Comment: @MrSmooth http://www.gamezone.com/products/battlefield-3/news/dice-announces-first-battlefield-3-double-xp-weekend

Comment: Yeah, I just read that on another site. I'm amazed that it hasn't been mentioned anywhere on Battlelog.

Answer (score -2):

I've been getting as high as ~7653. Maybe if you get *so* many ribbons that it just tells you how many you got, you'll get these added points instead, but that's just my guess.